# Получаю ошибку при вызове в useEffect асинхронного экшена, как это исправить?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

При вызове асинхронного экшена в useEffect получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch<UserAction>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.   Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: Dispatch<UserAction>) => Promise<void>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
```

**Компонент где сам запрос**

```
export const fetchUsers = () => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch<UserAction>) => {
        try{
            dispatch({type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS})
            const response = await $api.get('/users')
            dispatch({type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS, payload:response.data})
        } catch (e) {
            dispatch({
                type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_ERROR,
                payload: 'User loading error'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Компонент где делаю запрос в useEffect**

```
export const Users: React.FC = () => {
    const {users,error,loading} = useTypedSelector(state =>state.user)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect( () => {
    dispatch(fetchUsers())
    },[])

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
};
```

**Компонент где сами типы**

```
export enum UserActionTypes {
    FETCH_USERS = 'FETCH_USERS',
    FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS',
    FETCH_USERS_ERROR = 'FETCH_USERS_ERROR'
}

interface FetchUsersAction {
    type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS
}

interface FetchUsersSuccessAction {
    type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS;
    payload: any[]
}

interface FetchUsersErrorAction {
    type: UserActionTypes.FETCH_USERS_ERROR;
    payload:string;
}

export type UserAction = FetchUsersAction | FetchUsersSuccessAction | FetchUsersErrorAction

export interface UserState {
    users: any[];
    loading: boolean;
    error: null | string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я сделал вот так:

```
const dispatch: any = useDispatch()
```

в `useEffect` в подобной ситуации, и код выполнился без ошибки, попробуйте. Добавил условие `: any`